# Are these three systems of linear equations related?

Tags: linear-algebra

a) $\quad\left\{\begin{array}{r}{2 x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}=3} \\ {-x_{1}+2 x_{2}+4 x_{3}=6} \\ {x_{1}+x_{2}+5 x_{3}=9}\end{array}\right.$

b) $\quad\left\{\begin{array}{c}{2 x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}=4} \\ {-x_{1}+2 x_{2}+4 x_{3}=6} \\ {x_{1}+x_{2}+5 x_{3}=9}\end{array}\right.$

c) $\quad\left\{\begin{array}{r}{2 x_{1}-x_{2}+2 x_{3}=4} \\ {-x_{1}+2 x_{2}+4 x_{3}=6} \\ {x_{1}+x_{2}+5 x_{3}=9}\end{array}\right.$

Are these equation related? I can't see that they are.

I was ask to solve them. But if I can solve one system and conclude something useful about the others it will be great!

Answer (score 0):

For a) Multiplying the second equation by $2$ and adding to the first
$$2x_1-x_2+x_3=3$$
$$3x_2+9x_3=15$$
Doing the same $$-2$$ and adding to the first we get
$$-3x_2-9x_3=-15$$
Can you proceed?
Doing the same steps with b) we get
$$2x_1-x_2+x_3=4$$
$$3x_2+9x_3=16$$
$$-3x_2-9x_3=-16$$
For the last system we get
$$2x_1-x_2+2x_3=4$$
$$-3x_2+10x_3=16$$
$$-3x_2-8x_3=16$$

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is?

Comment: Then make the steps which i have written and read your question

Answer (score 0):

The first system is dependent and you have infinitely many  solutions because the third row is the sum of the first two rows.

The second system is inconsistent because the sum of the first two rows compared to the third row implies $10=9$ so  it does not have any solution.

The third system is consistent and has a unique solution of $$ (x,y,z)=(2,2,1)$$